# Can't import libpgm.graphskeleton, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dictionary'

Tags: python, probability

I need to build a Bayesian Network using naive bayes with libpgm.
The BN structure is known, so I just need to import it as a GraphSkeleton object with libpgm.graphskeleton.

When I run the code, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X\Documents\Modelli Probabilistici\0-NEW\reteBayesiana1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from libpgm.graphskeleton import GraphSkeleton
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\libpgm\graphskeleton.py", line 29, in <module>
    from dictionary import Dictionary
<b>ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dictionary'</b>
```

I installed the library using "pip3 install libpgm" and I didn't get any errors during the installation.

Here is my Code:

```py
import libpgm
from libpgm.graphskeleton import GraphSkeleton

skel = GraphSkeleton()
skel.load("skeleton.txt")
...
```

I checked my libraries folder and libpgm seems to be installed correctly, also there are both a 'graphskeleton.py' file and a 'dictionary.py' file and they both seem to have the objects needed (GraphSkeleton and Dictionary, which is required for 'graphskeleton.py')

Comment: Tried installing `dictionary` through pip?

Comment: Yes, but it seems to be unrelated to libpgm.
I still get the same error